# problems with DSolve in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I would like to solve this system of differential equations with Mathematica 7, but I found an error that says that the function was specified without dependence on all the independent variables.
The equations are:
[image]

Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: Does the indexing/subscripting with x or y have any special meaning (like differentiation) or is r_x just a name?

Comment: It's more of a sequence of differential equations than a system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have V7 handy but does this help?

```
DSolve[{D[x[t], t] == r1 - g1 x[t], 
  D[y[t], t] == k2 x[t]/(K + x[t]) g2 y[t]}, {x, y}, t]
```

Comment: Both version 7 and 8 give the same answer which appears to be correct.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `-` sign before the `g2` in your `y'[t]` equation. The `DSolve` struggles a bit if you fix that.

Comment: Yes, indeed I did miss that sign. Sorry about that. There seem to be other open questions like the meaning of \gamma_x and such.

Answer (score 0):

About the error you saw, it's hard to say exactly what you did wrong without seeing your code. But hopefully the code below will help clarify whatever mistake you happened to have made.

---

Now to solve the system of DEs. You can first solve the `x` DE:

```
In[1]:= xSoln = DSolve[{x'[t] == r1 - g1 x[t]}, x, t]

Out[1]= {{x -> Function[{t}, r1/g1 + E^(-g1 t) C[1]]}}
```

This can be substituted into the `y` DE to give a 1st order, linear, inhomogeneous differential equation, which can be solved with an integrating factor.

```
In[2]:= y'[t] == k2 x[t]/(k + x[t]) - g2 y[t] /. xSoln[[1]]

Out[2]= y'[t] == - g2 y[t]  
                 + (k2 (r1/g1 + E^(-g1 t) C[1]))/(k + r1/g1 + E^(-g1 t) C[1])
```

Call the inhomogeneous mess  `f[t]`, so the DE is `y'[t] == f[t] - g2 y[t]`.
Mathematica can solve this

```
In[3]:= y[t] /. DSolve[y'[t] == f[t] - g2 y[t], y, t][[1]]

Out[3]= C[1] E^(-g2 t) + E^(-g2 t) Integrate[E^(g2 K[1]) f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, t}]
```

Note that the integration constant `C[1]` is not the same as that in the `x[t]` solution.
Also that, when you substitute in the explicit form of `f[t]`, Mathematica can not do the integral in closed form.

So the best that we can do is

```
x[t] == r1/g1 + E^(-g1 t) C[1]
y[t] == C[2] E^(-g2 t) + E^(-g2 t) Integrate[E^(g2 s) f[s], s]
```

where

```
f[s] == k2 (r1 E^(g1 s) + g1 C[1])/((g1 k + r1)E^(g1 s) + g1 C[1])
```

Comment: Simon, congratulations on 10K! :D

Comment: (btw, I'm not voting only because I'm just passing through, not actually reading answers, but I had to say something when I saw **Simon 10k**.)